# What would be considered straight asp.net? (not mvc and not webforms)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I know the difference between ASP.NET webforms and ASP.NET MVC and I've seen quite a few videos explaining that they both run on top of ASP.NET (and I've used both).  However, my question is, how would one develop right on top of ASP.NET without webforms or mvc.net?  Would this be the equivalent of having a project with only .ASHX files?

Comment: I'm not sure this is even an answerable question.  Microsoft would be the ones to be able to clarify this, and I've never seen anything from them defining the term.  Anything else we put is a guess, although some people's guesses are better than others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASP.NET 1.0 and 1.1 originally consisted of a class library and templating markup (Web Forms).  This was a natural extension of ASP 3.0, where HTML and VB code were intermixed in an .ASP file.

The class library is what I would consider the "straight" ASP.NET framework.  IMHO, the System.Web namespace represents the efforts to incorporate "ASP" into the .NET framework.  You get the top-level objects like HttpContext object and its static properties, as well as a couple objects that do the lifting of the ASP.NET processing pipeline, IHttpModule- and IHttpHandler-derived classes.

Ostensibly, you could invent your own markup language and write an HttpModule (among other components) to render the responses.  This is probably why the System.Web namespace has grown to include code for Web Services, AJAX/JSON, MVC, and in .NET 3.5SP1, [ASP.NET dynamic data](http://www.asp.net/(S(y3u2uc45kakrr555dijiwvf2))/DynamicData/).

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

Where do web services fit into this?  A service isn't really a form nor is it MVC, so that would also be on the list of other things you could do with ASP.Net.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an IHttpHandler to intercept raw web requests from IIS and give any responces back whether it is a webform, image, file or whatever. which I guess could be considered basic ASP.NET without a WebForm or MVC. [Problem using IHttpHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385945/problem-using-ihttphandler)

Comment: aspx pages are not unique to webforms, they're the html part of the templating system asp.net provides.

Answer (score 3):

New answer:  I actually took the time to look up [Microsoft's official answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w3ex9c2.aspx).

> ASP.NET is a unified Web development
>   model that includes the services
>   necessary for you to build
>   enterprise-class Web applications with
>   a minimum of coding. ASP.NET is part
>   of the .NET Framework, and when coding
>   ASP.NET applications you have access
>   to classes in the .NET Framework. You
>   can code your applications in any
>   language compatible with the common
>   language runtime (CLR), including
>   Microsoft Visual Basic, C#, JScript
>   .NET, and J#. These languages enable
>   you to develop ASP.NET applications
>   that benefit from the common language
>   runtime, type safety, inheritance, and
>   so on.
>
> ASP.NET includes:
>
> A page and controls framework
>
> The ASP.NET compiler
>
> Security infrastructure
>
> State-management facilities
>
> Application configuration
>
> Health monitoring and performance
>   features
>
> Debugging support
>
> An XML Web services framework
>
> Extensible hosting environment and
>   application life cycle management
>
> An extensible designer environment

Comment: I know this is gonna sound weird but I think that first bullet point is incorrect since its clearly talking about the system.web.ui namespace

Comment: Ah, true but, (and I mean this in a lighthearted way because I see your point and agree with it) since it is Microsoft and Microsoft alone that can officially define  what ASP.NET is, mine is technically the "right" answer because it's copied verbatim from their site.  However, I am still giving my support to the point leader as having a good answer.  I just wanted to be nit-picky for a change.

Comment: It's like with Star Trek TOS - the books can say what they want, but the TV series is considered the "official" source of truth.

Comment: lol yeah, I will give you a +1 either way and for the star trek reference :)  Someone should email Scott Gu and see what he has to say about this

Comment: +1 for this answer and comments! Time for Scott Gu to do some retconning: "MVC? oh yeah, it was a secret 'page and controls framework' that we were sitting on, until RoR forced our hand..."

Comment: Wow I had to lookup what retcon meant, learn something every day I guess lol

Answer (score 1):

Asp.Net encompasses the System.Web namespace. Webforms is the System.Web.UI namespace. One of the critical differences is that the classes within System.Web.UI typically do not emit standards based html and SEO can be a nightmare.

Asp.Net on it's own can provide a basic templating system similar to many other web frameworks and the developer can make complete websites without using any WebForms controls. This is an atypical situation however because the typical Asp.Net development process, prior to Asp.Net Ajax and Asp.Net MVC anyway, was to use the controls in the toolbox.